# Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('type name')

Tags: .net, pointers, string, struct

this error stops compiling if i have one or more System.String in my structs
is there any other way to store strings?

i have tried things like this:

```
private long _B_ID;
private byte[] _C_Name;
private byte[] _C_Address;
private byte[] _C_Telephone;
```

but it is not seeming to work.

Comment: What are you doing with the structs? More info needed …

Comment: @n535:that was the first code,and the code in my question is the second.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph:I am getting them from a UdpClient copying them to unmanaged memory and trying to convert them to the real struct.

Comment: Could you then be more specific?

Comment: @n535: i stoped using pointers,i am using System.Runtime.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.and having fun with super fast speed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only get the address of a struct if it is blittable, i.e. it doesn't contain references.
See [Blittable and Non-Blittable Types(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare a Pointer to Non-fixed types even if you use "unsafe". To remove this error, You HAVE to specify size of the arrays along with keyword fixed.

For Example, _C_Name contains 25 bytes. So declare it as:

```
private fixed byte _C_Name[25];
```

Strings are Fixed typed so you was not getting error when you declare them as String.
Hope it works for you!

Regards!

Comment: Is this possible using generics. I have a generic class `MyClass<T>` with the `struct` type constraint applied and additional runtime checks to limit `<T>` to primitive integral and floating point types. In an unsafe method, I want to get a `void*` to a `fixed T []`. Is there a way to get around the compile-time restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `MarshalAs` attribute:

```
struct Foo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr]
    string s;
}
```