# Why can't get address of variable in unsafe-statement?

Tags: c#

According to MSDN we can get address of variables in unsafe context.
We can get address of variable in unsafe declared methods but why can't get it in all unsafe context ?

```
static void Main(string[] args) {      
    //Managed code here
    unsafe {
        string str = "d";
        fixed (char* t = &str[0]) {// ERROR :  Cannot take the address of the given expression
        }
    }
    //Managed code here
}
```

Comment: What is `g`? How does it fail?

Comment: What's the error/behavior you're seeing?

Comment: sorry I will update question

Comment: Please specify which line is throwing the error.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal error is on fixed line.

Comment: Seems to be answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299153/cannot-take-the-address-of-get-the-size-of-or-declare-a-pointer-to-a-managed-t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just not valid C# syntax. A string is not an array, it only looks like one. Try:

```
unsafe 
{
   string str = "d";
   fixed (char* t = str) 
   {
       char c1 = *t;
       char c2 = t[0];
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not what MSDN says (or at least not how I understand it). From msdn's page on `fixed` -  `fixed (char* p = str) ... // equivalent to p = &str[0]`

Comment: Equivalent doesn't mean both will compile. `str[0]` is an indexer and won't work in `&str[0]` and not in `Foo(ref str[0])`

Comment: Yeah I'm not saying that won't solve the problem, only that the MSDN docs are misleading.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Acording to MSDN `fixed (char* p = str)` is valid. and that throw an error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string*' to 'char*'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: See my comments about `string*` on other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of obtaining a string's address is like this:

```
char* t = str
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx

Comment: This also didn't work. Error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'string*' to 'char*'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: `str` isn't `string*` so are you missing something?

Comment: @Mahdi did you forget to put it in a fixed statement?

Comment: Here is what I used `unsafe {string str = "d"; fixed (char* t = &str) {}}`