# Change value of an object pointer C#

Tags: c#, pointers

In C# is possible to do this in a unsafe context:

```
int number = 2;
WriteLine("Value: " + number); //Print 2

int* ptr = &number;
*ptr = 10;

WriteLine("Value: " + number); //Print 10
```

But how can I achive the same for an object?

```
var person = new Person("Elena", 20);
Person* ptr = &person; //Error

//void* ptr = &person;
ptr = new Person("Miguel", 30); //Error
```

In this example looks like is possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/how-to-access-a-member-with-a-pointer

Comment: which error do you get? the object in the sample is a `struct`, not a `class`, what about `Person`?

Comment: Is also a struct, I get "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type"

Comment: then probably [this would apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13300453/1132334) here.

Comment: I see, is because my struct contains a String.

Comment: I'm a little confusing about that, I can't create a pointer because I have a String. So its not possible to track the reference to any struct like that and change its value?

Comment: The answer by Hans in the duplicate answers your question with a very good detail. If you don't understand the answer, then you are probably altogether wrong trying to use pointers in c#

Comment: sure smells XY to me. Why do you want to do this - this is extreme corner case stuff

Comment: But there is a trick to point to manage memory in C#? The new Span<T> in 4.7.2 allow you do that, but right now there is not source code, or at least I dont found it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define pointer to a `ReferenceType` at all.
For `ValueType` you can use pointer to point them

```
int number = 2;
int* ptr = &number; // Allowed

struct Person
{
    float score;
    int age;
}
Person person = new Person();
Person* pp = &person;  // Allowed

struct Person
{
    string name;
    float score;
    int age;
}
Person person = new Person();
Person* pp = &person;  // Not Allowed, Because you can't get pointer to ReferenceType
```

But ReferenceType is already pointer but not in `unsafe` manner, there are safe and managed by GC.

```
class Person
{
    public string name;
    public float score;
    public int age;
}

Person ptr1 = new Person { name="Elena", score= 10, age= 20 };
ptr2 = ptr1;
ptr2.name="Miguel";
Console.WriteLine("Value: " + ptr1.name); // prints Miguel
```

Comment: In case Person is a struct use pointer is something imposible at the moment?

Comment: If `Person` is a struct (which is ValueType) and all of its fields also are `ValueType` (e.g. int, float, struct, ...), it is possible to define pointer to it.

Comment: Thanks, is pretty much clear for me, I was wrong about the c# concept of pointers.

Comment: I'd just like to point to the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code) where it says: "The type specified before the * in a pointer type is called the referent type. Only an unmanaged type can be a referent type.". [Unmanaged types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/unmanaged-types) are: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, float, double, decimal, or bool, enums, pointers, user-defined struct with only unmanaged types as fields and is , in C# 7.3 and earlier, not a constructed type.